# Accessing image module for python in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, python-2.7, imagemagick

how do i access the ImageOps module for python in ubuntu 12.4. I wanted to use inbuilt image processing functions but m unable to acess those.Can someone tell me that how do i aceess that module.there is an import error like ImageOps module is missing.what should i do?

Comment: i've tried whatever u suggest.but still i'm unable to access inbuilt functions.like i wanted to process image by applying some kind of different filter operations.and also i wanted to use some functions eg.inverting image we can use ImageOps.invert(image)

Comment: but i am still unable to use those functions.pls help m

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the `python-imaging` package installed:

```bash
sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

Then, from the Python prompt, enter

```py
from PIL import ImageOps
```

If you don't get any errors, then everything installed correctly and you're ready to use PIL/Pillow in your programs.